# MySQL UPDATE / DELETE deadlock using modulo

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I have a table with an column `user_id`, which is an integer index. There's a number of processes that have to pick non-conflicting users and do some processing. I am using modulo for this, so at some point, they will do (e.g. in the case of 4 threads):

```
UPDATE table SET data = x WHERE user_id % 4 = y;
```

Where y is 0 to 3, to mark which specific thread is working. MySQL can't use the user_id index like that unfortunately, so it seems to lock all the table to scan it. This causes deadlocks if it only has a READ lock, while another process is doing something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE user_id = z;
```

What do you think the best way to deal with this would be?

I am thinking I could have a separate `SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE user_id % 4 = y` query, get the results (it will be a few hundred) and then do the update with a `user_id IN (...)` instead.
I am not sure how locks work for nested selects, so could perhaps:

```
UPDATE table SET data = x WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id from table WHERE user_id % 4 = y)
```

also work, to avoid fetching the SELECT results to do the UPDATE?

Otherwise I guess I could use LOCK TABLES etc, but I'd think that's not nice, so I am curious whether there's something else to consider.

Comment: In some situations, "gap locks" cause trouble.  4 such threads will lock all the rows and perhaps all the gaps.  You are into an area where InnoDB may be locking more than is necessary, but limiting the locking further would be too costly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temporary table containing the IDs you want. Then you can join with this and it should only lock those rows.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_ids AS
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE id % 4 = @y;

UPDATE table AS t
JOIN temp_ids as i ON t.id = i.id
SET t.data = @x;
```

I don't think it will work if you join with a subquery or CTE, because I suspect that will keep the table locked for the duration of the combined query.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it can be done with a single query. I think I'll go with a temporary table, it is reasonably "clean" and seems to perform OK.